# PrimeNG - Autocomplete field with datatable for suggestions

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, ng-template

I am trying to have the suggestions from the PrimeNG autocomplete field display in a table with a header.

The biggest things are only displaying the table header for the first row and possibly eliminating the padding between the tables.  I am also hoping for a more optimal way to handle this because right now each suggestion is contained in its own table and I can see that being costly with a lot of suggestions being displayed in the drop down.

```
<p-autoComplete [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" 
    [(ngModel)]="customer" [suggestions]="customerResults" 
    (completeMethod)="searchCustomers($event)" field="name">
  <ng-template let-value let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
    <p-dataTable [value]="customerResults.slice(i, i+1)">
      <p-headerColumnGroup *ngIf="i === 0">
         <p-row>
           <p-column header="Id"></p-column>
           <p-column header="Name"></p-column>
         </p-row>
       </p-headerColumnGroup>
       <p-column field="id"></p-column>
       <p-column field="name"></p-column>
     </p-dataTable>
  </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5RXBeIWOnWHvY9R7KlnW?p=preview)